# Convert from Text to Date in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need your help in converting text - "Price FOR THE PERIOD 08/01/21 THROUGH 15/01/21       " to date 15/01/2021.

I am using the formula `=DATE(RIGHT(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(Edited!A2)," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))&"20",4),MID(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(Edited!A2)," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))&"20",4,2),LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(Edited!A2)," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))&"20",2))` but the output i am getting is 15/01/2120 instead of 15/01/2021.

Can someone please help on the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your string ends with an 8 character date followed by a space we can use:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(TRIM(Edited!A2),8),6) & RIGHT(RIGHT(TRIM(Edited!A2),8),2)+2000
```

[image]

**Note:**
This isolates the date and converts the 2 digit year into a 4 digit year
This can be made shorter if you are using **Excel 365**.
The result is a string and not a true Excel Date.

**EDIT#1:**

To put the month first:

```
=MID(RIGHT(TRIM(Edited!A2),8),4,3) & LEFT(RIGHT(TRIM(Edited!A2),8),3) & RIGHT(RIGHT(TRIM(Edited!A2),8),2)+2000
```

**EDIT#2:**

If you use **Excel 365**, then you make a real Excel date with:

```
=LET(d,RIGHT(TRIM(Edited!A2),8)    ,DATE(RIGHT(d,2)+2000,MID(d,4,2),LEFT(d,2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Great thank you so much for your response. Is it possible for me to have the format as mm/dd/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: @TejasGoswami  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 0):

Does this simple one work for you?

`=DATEVALUE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(Edited!A2)," ",REPT(" ",100)),100)))`

As you stated, 
`=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(Edited!A2)," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))` gets last string in the sentence, 
and then `=DATEVALUE()` converts the string to datetime data and the result depends your computers locale setting. 
In addition, you should set the column formatting as datetime and easily customize it (`mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` etc).

If you know the length of the date string at the end and it is fixed length, it will be more simple:
`=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(TRIM(Edited!A2),8))`

Comment: Thank you Takahar!